# What is the meaning of this sentence :"she drew up the blind in impatient jerks."

Tags: literature, sentence-meaning

What does this sentence mean?

"When she had finished her hasty dressing she drew up the blind in impatient jerks".

And what does "gulf" mean here? :

"Between the long gulf of dark houses"

thanks in advance

Comment: 'impatient jerks' are those guys behind you that honk just as the light has turned green.

Comment: She is jerking (pulling sharply) impatiently at the rope that pulls up the venetian blinds covering the windows.

Comment: Oh thanksss I've been wrestling with this " blind " and couldn't make any sense out of it.

Comment: It's annoying but words have multiple meanings, sometimes you have to go through all the definitions to find the one that fits, and then even metaphorical uses are not listed. BUt here 'blind' is venetian blinds, the window cover, and 'jerks' are not bad people, just short tugs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! In addition to the [guidelines on asking good questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), please ask only 1 question per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st sentence: It seems like she overall was in a rush to get somewhere. She got dressed in a rush, pulled the blinds up/ open impatiently. 
 
If you've ever opened, or closed blinds slowly or patiently, the blinds can move in a smooth motion. 

2nd sentence: 
Gulf in this sentence is a descriptor of undefined/ambiguous space. So, a long gulf of dark houses gives the imagery of maybe a neighborhood at night with silhouettes of houses.